Why did studies find a within-person correlation between IQ and agreeableness but not between-person?
Bartels, 2012 found a correlation of 0.21 in what I understand to be within-person correlations (when one trait increased throughout life, the other did as well), however the between-person correlations don't seem significant.
I would expect that if the factors truly influenced each other positively, they would also be correlated between people. Is Bartels' finding statistically confounded? (e.g. via a change in response style) Or is there a way to reconcile these two findings?

Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you think Bartels is measuring within-person correlations?

Table 3 shows phenotypic correlations which are always accompanied by "(within person)" in the text

Ah, I see; they're using that to mean that the IQ and agreeableness are measured in the same person, in contrast to measures between twins where they correlate agreeableness in one twin with IQ in the other twin, not the way you are interpreting it.

@BryanKrause Oh, right, thanks! In that case, I'm just curious about the cause of this discrepancy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis is probably relevant. I would say that the statistical description in both papers is too sparse to interpret clearly what they've done. Unfortunately not atypical.
